# Cannot resolve symbol 'file'

Tags: java, android

I am trying access the camera on an android device, so I tried some code from this [site](https://androidkennel.org/android-camera-access-tutorial/)

I get this error: [image at Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCuwE.jpg) when I hover my mouse over 'file'. Take a look at the code below.

MainActivity.Java

```
package com.example.camera;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.io.File;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button takePictureButton;
    private ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        takePictureButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_image);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            takePictureButton.setEnabled(false);
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] { Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE }, 0);
        }
   }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == 0) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                takePictureButton.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }
    }

    public void takePicture(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        file = Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile());
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, file);

        startActivityForResult(intent, 100);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == 100) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                imageView.setImageURI(file);
            }
        }
    }

    private static File getOutputMediaFile(){
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "CameraDemo");

        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()){
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
                return null;
            }
        }

        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        return new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
                "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");
        }
    }
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:onClick="takePicture"
        android:text="Take a picture!"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

android_manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.camera">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Sorry if there are some formatting errors, I am quite new to Stack Overflow. The code is some testing for a future project. If anyone could answer my question on this error, +1 to you. I would really appreciate the help :)

Comment: You have not declared a variable or field named `file`. So, the compiler does not know what `file` is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare file variable globally.

Like:

```
private Uri file;
```

> **In Java**
>
> A variable is a container that holds values that are used in a
>   Java program. To be able to use a variable it needs to be declared.
>   Declaring variables is normally the first thing that happens in any
>   program.

Comment: You need to declare a Uri field as in my answer